# Is there any limitation when using summary report as a source report in reporting snapshot?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, field-mapping, analytic-snapshots

Is there any limitation when using summary report as a source report in reporting snapshot?

In reporting snapshot, while field mapping we are able see only group by fields and formula fields from the report and other are not able to being mapping. why?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any limitation when using summary report as a source report
>   in reporting snapshot?

Yes - the [usual limits for Analytic Snapshots](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_troubleshooting_snapshots.htm&language=en_US) apply - most notably, a max of 2000 rows per snapshot run

> In reporting snapshot, while field mapping we are able see only group by fields and formula fields from the report and other are not able to being mapping. why?

This threw me for a loop initially but it makes sense, each row of the report output is defined at the lowest level of summarization, and hence, only the group by fields and summarized columns are available. Non-summarized columns don't have unique values for a summarized line (*they are detail lines being summarized*)

Take an example detail report:

```
Geo   Region   Amount   CloseDate
NA    US       10000     2017-10-01
NA    US       20000     2017-10-06
NA    CA       30000     2017-10-12
EMEA  DE       40000     2017-10-01
EMEA  DE       30000     2017-10-04
```

The Summary report is this:

```
Geo  Region    Amount
NA   US        30000
NA   CA        30000
EMEA DE        70000
```

There is no way CloseDate or Name or Stage can be emitted to the snapshot (unless they are added to the grouping since dates/strings can't be summarized)

If you want to snapshot details, don't use a summary report as the source for the snapshot - but be cognizant of the 2,000 row limit per snapshot

Analytic Snapshots are a poor man's BI system in SFDC; they work best with summarized data for large orgs; smaller orgs can get away with snapping detail reports